# Prevent automount for new and unknown devices and volumes

Tags: mount, automount

For all of my known devices that I do not want mounted, I have a `fstab` entry that prevents them from being mounted automatically. What I want is either of the following.

1. All new and unknown devices (i.e. their UUID's won't be known ahead of time prior to plugging them in) should be treated as if `noauto` was set in its mounting options.
2. A way to treat `fstab` like a whitelist (e.g. to only mount certain devices and nothing else).

Why do I want this behaviour? I dunno.

This is technically a question for UNIX in general, but I am asking it here in case of any quirks specific to macOS.